# 2016 Chevy Silverado white smoke and the smell of oil

Tags: chevrolet, silverado

Just came out after a cold rainy day and started the truck as I was walking to it.  I saw white smoke coming out tailpipe and the smell of burnt oil or oil.  Didn't last long but should I be concerned? Only 20K and 18 months new.

Comment: If you have an issue, *any issue* with your new-ish truck, take it to the dealership and have them look at it. Yes, what you described is concerning, but could be one of many different things which you really need to have looked at. Your truck is still under warranty.

Comment: Diesel or gasoline?

Comment: Yes, took it over there. They could not find anything. Thank you for your response

Comment: It sounds like oil is leaking somewhere. Are you sure it was white smoke and not just normal cold weather, cold engine exhaust? Does it happen on sunny, warm days as well?

Answer (score 1):

No oil should be getting into your exhaust.

White smoke and smell of oil almost certainly means that there's oil vapour in the exhaust, so definitely get it checked out.

Have you been checking the engine oil level? Has it changed over time?

Head gasket failing?